# Xcode: Command LinkStoryboards failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard

There is another question about generic command failures in Xcode, but I want to specifically ask about the "LinkStoryboards" command. This build error occurred after deleting a storyboard from my project and no amount of cleaning or restarting Xcode would help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A LinkStoryboards failure means that the compiler could not find a storyboard used in a Storyboard Reference.

To fix my particular issue, I had to locate any Storyboard References to my deleted storyboard and delete those references.

Comment: To find storyboard references, you can look for something similar in the error log: `Did not find view controller with identifier "SomeVC" in Main.storyboard, referenced from SomeStoryboard.storyboard`

Answer (score 17):

In your second Storyboard set your initial view

[image]

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I have missed to add an entry point in my Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

When I looked under the show a **report navigator menu**, I realized that I had written the storyboardId wrong, when I corrected the file I saw there, the problem was solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was copy-pasting several views and supporting files.
When I copy-pasted everything in one folder I received this error.

So I copy-pasted views and supporting files one by one, cleaned the building folder and then everything started to work.